# ChiSq same in Excel, Numbers, but different in R. Why?

Tags: chi-squared-test

With this data...

Observed Cust Freq.:    31  18  36  23  47  60
Expected Cust.Freq.:    21.5    21.5    32.25   32.25   43  64.5

Excel and Numbers give 0.12876 as the p-value.

Yet, R, using this code:

```
library(MASS)
values <- matrix(c(31,18,36,23,47,60,21.50,21.50,32.25,32.25,43,64.50), nrow=2, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE )
values
chisq.test(values)
```

Gives:  **p-value = 0.5317**  (X-squared = 4.1243, df = 5)

If these two results weren't confusing enough, if I manually compute X-square, I get a different result from either (8.54)

A bit confused here.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are doing a chi-square test of independence when you should be doing a chi-square goodness of fit test.

```
> obs <- c(31,18,36,23,47,60)
> exp <- c(21.50,21.50,32.25,32.25,43,64.50)
> exp_prop <- exp/sum(obs)
> chisq.test(x = obs, p = exp_prop)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  obs
X-squared = 8.5426, df = 5, p-value = 0.1288
```